# Preimage of Union is Union of Preimage

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Struggling on what steps to take to construct a successful proof for this. This will be the last. Can I get a verification? I think the approach and logic is wrong.

Prove:

If $f:A \rightarrow B$ is a function with domain $A$ and $T_i$ with $i \in I$ is a family of sets where $\forall i \in I$,$T_i \subseteq B$ then

$f^{-1}( 
\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} T_{i})= \bigcup\limits_{i \in I}f^{-1} (T_{i})$

Proving Subset both ways

Prove
$f^{-1}( 
\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} T_{i}) \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{i \in I}f^{-1} (T_{i})$

Assume $s \in f^{-1}( 
\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} T_{i})$

$\implies$ $f(s) \in \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} T_{i}$

$(\exists i \in I)$ s.t. $f(s) \in  T_{i}$

$(\exists i \in I)$ s.t. $s \in f^{-1} (T_{i})$

So

$f^{-1}( 
\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} T_{i}) \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{i \in I}f^{-1} (T_{i})$

Next Prove

$f^{-1}( 
\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} T_{i}) \supseteq \bigcup\limits_{i \in I}f^{-1} (T_{i})$

Assume

$s \in \bigcup\limits_{i \in I}f^{-1} (T_{i})$

$\implies (\exists i \in I)$ s.t. $s \in f^{-1}(T_i)$

$\implies (\exists i \in I)$ s.t. $f(s) \in T_i$

$\implies f(s)\in  \bigcup\limits_{i \in I}T_{i}$

$\implies s \in f^{-1}(\bigcup\limits_{i \in I}T_{i})$

Comment: Your steps are correct.

Comment: Your proof looks fine. Intuitively, if I am an element, then my image being in the union of a family of sets means the same thing as my image being in one of those sets.